# How to write this non-linear Epsilon-Delta proof w/ a radical?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta, advice

**The question: Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 9} 2+\sqrt{x} = 5$.**

*After reading this link from Milefoot on [how to construct a non-linear delta-epsilon proof](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm) (second example), this is what I came up with (sorry if this isn't the correct way of writing it):*

$|x - 9| < \delta \Rightarrow 0 < |f(x) - 5|< \epsilon$

$|(2 + \sqrt{x}) -5| = |\sqrt{x} -3| < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon < \sqrt{x}-3 < \epsilon$

$(-\epsilon+3)^2 < x < (\epsilon + 3)^2$

$(-\epsilon+3)^2 -9 < x -9< (\epsilon + 3)^2-9$

$\epsilon^2 - 6\epsilon < x -9< \epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon $

*Therefore, this works if you define $\delta$ as $\min{(\epsilon^2 - 6\epsilon,\epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon )}$.*

However, the [solution on the UC Davis website](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preclimsoldirectory/PrecLimSol.html#SOLUTION%2010) was substantially different. Their final answer was $\delta$ as $\min{(1,(8+\sqrt{3})\epsilon)}$. I realize that there may be several valid answers for a delta-epsilon proof, but the way I did is was so different, and honestly it's a concept I'm struggling with. Could anyone please look over my solution to check if I'm wrong, and if so, where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the limit $5$? You never mentioned it in the question.

Comment: "The question" has no verb.  Perhaps it equals something?  Or maybe we are to "find" or "compute" something?

Comment: Let $\epsilon=1/10$. Your suggested $\delta$ is negative.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget to say that the limit was 5! Edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is correct up to $$\epsilon^2 - 6\epsilon < x -9< \epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon.$$  In the given guide, $|x-c|<\delta \iff -\delta < x-c < \delta$.

Observe that $$\epsilon^2 - 6\epsilon = \epsilon (\epsilon -6)
\begin{cases}
\ge 0 &\text{if } x \le 0 \text{ or } x \ge 6,\\
<0 &\text{if } 0 < x < 6.
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, if $0 < \epsilon < 1$, the $\delta$ should be defined as $\min\{6\epsilon - \epsilon^2,\epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon \}$.  Then $|x-9|<\delta$ implies $$|x-9| < 6\epsilon - \epsilon^2 \text{ and } |x-9| < \epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon$$
$$\implies 9-x < 6\epsilon - \epsilon^2 \text{ and } x-9 < \epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon$$
$$\iff \epsilon^2 - 6\epsilon < x-9 < \epsilon^2 + 6\epsilon$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just wondering, though this is probably a terrible question—what is epsilon isn't between 0 and 1? Or does it not matter as long as the proof is valid for some values of epsilon?

Comment: @jess1901 A.P. points out the problem of $-1<0$ in your approach:
$$-\epsilon < \sqrt{x}-3 < \epsilon \iff 3 - \epsilon < \sqrt{x} < 3 + \epsilon.$$  I added the condition $0 < \epsilon < 1$ so that $$(-\epsilon+3)^2 < x < (\epsilon + 3)^2$$ is a legitimate step since $$0 < 3 - \epsilon < 3 + \epsilon.$$
Btw, as a "non-new" user, I've done the upvote for you.

Comment: Upvotes all around! I think this is the better answer; although less concise than mine, it addresses OP's concerns in more detail and, in the end, is probably more useful overall.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring inequalities involving potentially negative numbers is a recipe for disaster; consider for instance squaring both sides of the inequality $-1 < 0$...

Instead note that $|\sqrt x - 3| < \epsilon \iff |\sqrt x-3|^2 < \epsilon^2$, and that $|\sqrt x-3|^2 \leq |\sqrt x-3||\sqrt x+3| = |x - 9|$. Thus it suffices to take $\delta = \epsilon^2$.

Note that our choice of $\delta$ doesn't even depend on the particular number $9$ here; this says that the square root function is [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Comment: Thanks so much :) This is a really clear & concise solution; in fact, more so than the "official" solution which used conjugates, taking the min of 1 and (something) epsilon etc. (I would upvote but I'm new to Stack).